# Http redirect to Https and SEO with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, seo, http-status-code-301

I am wondering if I should keep the GET pages off SSL, while the POST of that same URL on SSL?  I am reading issues with doing redirects of required pages that need SSL with SEO.  ASP.NET MVC has an attribute that however does a 302 redirect instead of a 301.  Is there a best practice in doing this with SEO.  I have pages such as Login, Register, an Account page.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, in terms of SEO, the principles don't apply to forms as the spider doesn't try to complete the forms, so the redirects from these pages doesn't affect them.  It is just static links etc that they follow.

The main thing to worry about with SEO on a password protected site is ensuring that paid/private content doesn't end up in the search engine etc etc.

/* edit */

In terms of the redirect, I wouldn't use a flag on the controller to action this.  If a site must be viewed via the https protocol, then I would set the Require SSL property on the directory in IIS and handle the 403.4 error specifically to issue a permanent redirect to the place the person was trying to access.

This will ensure any static pages that are accessed are pulled through the https protocol too.

Si

Comment: I dont think you answered anything with regards to https and 301 redirects.